# Scrapy not finding table

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy, ipython

I am trying to scrape data from the table in http://www.oddsportal.com/basketball/usa/nba-2014-2015/results/

The particular table I want has class="table-main"

running from scrapy response.xpath('//table')

```
In [28]:  response.xpath('//table')
Out[28]:
[<Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t<td c
lass="bol'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table class="table-main top-event">\n\t\t\t'>
,
 <Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>\n\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t<tab'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table class="rm-bonus-offer">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
\t<'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table>\n\t\t\t\t\t<tr>\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<td>\n\t\
t\t\t\t\t\t<tab'>,
 <Selector xpath='//table' data=u'<table class="rm-bonus-offer">\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t
\t<'>]
```

does not return the table I wish to scrape. Can anyone help?

Comment: you can get that with `'id("tournamentTable")'`, but check that the information inside it is loaded dynamically. Use `firebug` (or something similar) to check which request (another from the original) contains `tournamentTable`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use...

```
sel.xpath('.//table[starts-with(@class, "table-main")]')
```

or

```
sel.xpath('.//div[@id="top-event-box"]/table')
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the table by response.xpath('//*[@id="tournamentTable"]')

Answer (score 0):

```
Selector(response).xpath('//table[contains(@class, "table-main")]').extract_first()
```

I've tested, it works.

See [Selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/1.0/topics/selectors.html) in scrapy doc